# Bluetooth Thermal printer print half String

Tags: android, thermal-printer

Please help me, I waste my whole day but could not figure out Why my Thermal Printer print half text in receipt. It's work perfectly in `58mm Mini Bluetooth Thermal Printer`. But when I come in Thermal Printer `LESHP 80mm Wireless Bluetooth Thermal` this printer only print half text in receipt.

Here my code:

```
void findBT() {

    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                if (device.getName().contains("Printer")) {

                    mmDevice = device;

                }
            }



        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"device not pair.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 void SendDateBT() throws IOException {
    try {

        // Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
        mmOutputStream.write(mytext.getBytes());

        mmOutputStream.flush();
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call this two function when I want to print receipt :

```
findBT();
SendDatBt();
```

Comment: Is it possible the device stops printing on connection close? Try adding a sleep for 20s after the flush call. Does it print more? If so then look if the API provides a way of waiting for the job to finish in a clean way (i.e. not just sleeping for an arbitrary amount of time).

Comment: Please provide an image about the printed documents

Comment: Further to my other comment have you tried sending an EOF?

Comment: Thank you for reply  I have try this after lot of searching mmOutputStream.write(Mytext.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
Finally its work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try this after lot of searching and its work for me.

```
mmOutputStream.write(Mytext.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"‌​)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a pause after write the data , trying with 1-2 seconds before flush and close the connection.
This is the application that I wrote: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp